# with repeated measure dataset how do i delete unwanted ids?

Tags: sas

Here is the the structure of my data below:

I only need `ID 2` since all patients are alive, therefore trying to delete `ID 1`:

```
ID   sex  status

1      2       A

1      2       A

1      2       A

1      2       D

2      1       A

2      1       A

2      1       A
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you just need to delete a specific (already known) ID from the dataset or you need a more general code that would delete those IDs that not all are alive?

Comment: @bastelflp: i printed to see those who fell under certain conditions, and manually copied their ids to do an if then delete option. I was looking for easier way to tackle that, cus if I have 100 id like that I may not be able to hand type all to delete them.

Comment: @Dmitry, yes I am looking for a code that enables me to delete all IDs that fall under a certain condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to delete the records from your source dataset, you can do so with:

```
PROC SQL;
   DELETE FROM MyData WHERE ID = 1;
QUIT;
```

However, if you want to retain the source dataset as-is; maybe you will use it again, it would be best to create a new dataset from it, like so:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE MyFilteredData AS
   SELECT ID, sex, status
   FROM MyData
   WHERE ID = 2;
QUIT;
```

or

```
DATA MyFilteredData;
   SET MyData;
   IF ID = 2;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
    delete from your_data where id ~= 2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This `PROC SQL` will create a new dataset `Want` from the original dataset `Have` including only IDs that have no status="D":

```
proc sql;
    create table Want as
    select *
    from Have
    where ID not in
        (select distinct ID
         from Have
         where status="D")
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Why would you use a sub-query for that? Why not: `where status ~= 'D'` instead?

Comment: Because my understanding is that the goal is to delete those IDs that have at least one 'D' even if the same ID has also 'A's